# undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()' when adding boost/asio

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I want to use boost.asio header in my project, but when I include it's .hpp file I got this output error on compile:

- I need boost.asio for crow to route my web request.

  /home/john/Downloads/clion-1.2.4/bin/cmake/bin/cmake --build /home/john/.CLion12/system/cmake/generated/a3f08900/a3f08900/Release --target rcp -- -j 8
  [ 50%] Linking CXX executable /home/john/projects/rightChoiceProperty/bin/rcp
  CMakeFiles/rcp.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `_GLOBAL__sub_I_main':
  main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x53): undefined reference to`boost::system::generic_category()'
  main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x58): undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
  main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x5d): undefined reference to`boost::system::system_category()'
  main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x62): undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
  collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
  CMakeFiles/rcp.dir/build.make:94: recipe for target '/home/john/projects/rightChoiceProperty/bin/rcp' failed
  make[3]: *** [/home/john/projects/rightChoiceProperty/bin/rcp] Error 1
  CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/rcp.dir/all' failed
  make[2]:**  [CMakeFiles/rcp.dir/all] Error 2
  CMakeFiles/Makefile2:79: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/rcp.dir/rule' failed
  make[1]:  **[CMakeFiles/rcp.dir/rule] Error 2
  Makefile:118: recipe for target 'rcp' failed
  make: *** [rcp] Error 2

I'm using CLion 1.2.4 as IDE
this is my main.cpp content:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Hello, World!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And this is my CMakeLists.txt file content:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
project(rcp)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -lboost_system")

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)

set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin")

include_directories("libraries/boost")

add_executable(rcp ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

Thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-l` option is not a compiler option, it's a *linker* options, so you're setting it for the wrong variable as `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` are only for the compiler.

Instead use e.g. [`target_link_libraries`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/command/target_link_libraries.html) to add libraries. Like

```
target_link_libraries(rcp boost_system)
```

---

But what you *really* should do is to find the system-installed Boost libraries and use those. You do that with [`find_package`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/command/find_package.html):

```
find_package(Boost
    REQUIRED COMPONENTS asio system)

include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(rcp ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```